# Non-research level question

Tags: discussion, migration

I just gave an answer to the following question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153157/a-lemma-on-the-growth-of-the-number-of-certain-edge-paths-for-a-given-train-trac/153170

but I think the whole thing should be migrated to MathematicsStackExchange.

Comment: I'd be happy to migrate the question, but I don't think the answer would be migrated with it. Want me to go ahead?

Comment: Go for it. I've copied the answer.

Comment: Okay, it's been migrated.

Comment: The answer was migrated as well, so no worries.  Thanks.